# Test set cookies function with Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, js-cookie

Does someone knows how can I test this function in Jest? I don't have any ideas at this moment, maybe I need to mock Cookies ?

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const setUserCookie = () => {
  if (!Cookies.get("UserToken")) {
    Cookies.set("UserToken", uuidv4(), { expires: 10 });
  }
};

export default setUserCookie;
```

I tried this for now, but I don't know if this is correct, I don't think it tests the functionality of my function:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import setCookie from './setCookie';


describe("setCookie", () => {
  it("should set cookie", () => {
    const mockSet = jest.fn();
    Cookies.set = mockSet;
    Cookies.set('testCookie', 'testValue');
    setCookie()
    expect(mockSet).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: [Mocking modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) is likely to be what you want to do.  Bear in mind that if you modify an import directly you'd need to undo those changes or risk altering the behaviour of all subsequent tests (which I think module modules helps with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to test this is to utilize the actual logic, so I would change your test to the following:

```
it("should set cookie", () => {
    // execute actual logic
    setCookie();
    // retrieve the result
    const resultCookie = Cookies.get();
    // expects here
    expect(resultCookie["UserToken"]).toBeTruthy();
    // expects for other values here...
  });
```

To note, `uuidv4()` will generate a new value for every new test run, meaning that you cannot expect the same value for the `"UserToken"` property. Instead, you can use the following approach to tackle this problem:

First set up a spy for it:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
jest.mock('uuid');
```

Then add its mock implementation with the expected result into the unit test:

```
const expectedUUIDV4 = 'testId';
uuidv4.mockImplementation(() => expectedUUIDV4);
// then expecting that in the result
expect(resultCookie["UserToken"]).toEqual(expectedUUIDV4);
```